# Plugin Summernote fullscreen problema modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

Estou utilizando o plugin Summernote para a criação de conteúdo dentro de um sistema. Mas quando estou em fullscreen e tento adicionar um link ou imagem, a modal respectiva aparece atrás do backdrop do bootstrap. Já testei alterar as z-indexes, mas sem sucesso. Alguma sugestão? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Obtive uma solução de outra forma, porém bem simples sem alterar no código já existente. Cria-se uma classe no CSS:

```
<style>
    /* Amplia o modal para preencher toda tela*/
    .bodyFullscreen {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Lembrando que deve vir após a inserção do código do bootstrap e summernote, para evitar conflitos.
O código abaixo é o evento(ação) de click sobre o botão de fullscreen no modal. Esta bem documentado para evitar dúvidas:

```
// Evento de click no botao fullscreen
$('body').on('click', '#modalNome [data-event=fullscreen]', function(event){

    // Modal que esta sendo exibido
    var modal = $('#modalNome .modal-dialog');

    // Verifica se modal possui a classe bodyFullscreen, se possuir a remove, caso contrario insere
    if(!modal.hasClass('bodyFullscreen')){
        modal.addClass('bodyFullscreen');
    }else{
        modal.removeClass('bodyFullscreen');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode corrigir esse problema adicionando o atributo `z-index: -1` na classe `modal-backdrop`.

Outras considerações:

- Verifique se o seu modal está fora de qualquer `div` ou elemento da sua página, sempre coloque-os antes da sua tag `</body>`.
- Verifique se você **não está** incluindo o `bootstrap.js` **antes** do `bootstrap.css`.

[Exemplo no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tjgow7ej/)

<sub>Eu vi que você disse que já tentou alterar os `z-index`, porém eu estava com esse mesmo problema, tentava por o `z-index` do modal maior que o do backdrop e também não funcionava.</sub>

Comment: Funcionou. Só tive que usar um !important nessa declaração. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.